# Return JSON from Express app: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, json, express

I need a pair of fresh eyes please.

I'm trying to get a simple Express app to return some json (it happens to be a Firebase token, but that's not relevant) every time a request is made to it.

This is my Express server code:

```
app.get('/validate', function (req, res) {
  var customToken = firebase.auth().createCustomToken(req.query.token);
  res.json({
    token: customToken
  });
});

app.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 8000');
});
```

And this is the request from the client (listening on port 3000):

```
export function login() {
    return fetch('http://localhost:8000/validate?token=666', {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: new Headers({
          'Authorization': apiClient.headers.Authorization,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
      })
      .then(response => console.log('RESPONSE: ', response.json()))
      .catch(response => console.error('ERROR: ', response));
  }
```

The Express app seems to be working fine because when I open `http://localhost:8000/validate?token=666` in a browser I can see the json I need.

However, when I make the client request I get this error

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

and this is what the Response log looks like

```
RESPONSE:  Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected", [[PromiseValue]]: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at SyntaxError (native)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (h…}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected"[[PromiseValue]]: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at SyntaxError (native)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main.js:1381:2), <anonymous>:78:42)message: "Unexpected end of input"stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input↵    at SyntaxError (native)↵    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main.js:1381:2), <anonymous>:78:42)"get stack: stack()set stack: stack()__proto__: Error
login.js?b88c:54
```

Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: try logging the raw response like `console.log(response)` and inspect

Comment: Not useful I'm afraid: `RESPONSE:  Response {type: "opaque", url: "", status: 0, ok: false, statusText: ""…} body: (...) bodyUsed: false headers: Headers null}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, I've solved my issue by adding

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

to the server side code.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem and after some researching I realized that the only reason `{ mode: 'no-cors' }` exist is for opaque response that cannot be accessed directly. To access the response you'll need to cache it with [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) and later on get it with a service worker.

I ended up solving that by adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to my server side (make sure this setup is safe for you in production and that you are absolutely sure that you are the only one who are able to make request to your server) + removing the `mode:'no-cors'` option from the request.

Comment: I did solve it with something along the lines you suggest.

Comment: I haven't accepted your answer because I've solved my problem _before_ you answered. But I've added +1 to reward your effort nonetheless.